# Project Server 2010

Tags: ms-project, project-server, ms-project-server-2010

For project server 2010, can a project have multiple owners to that one project?
Also I havea a project where the owner can not approve the timesheets(its a server issue) but can anybody else on that project approve the timesheets?

thanks
Lauren

Answer (score 1):

Project Server can have multiple status manager (Means Task Approver). The Time sheet is approved by Time Sheet Manager. So any body in the project, if they are Time Sheet Manager for that particular resource can approve.